# All roles unable to access a protected endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure an endpoint using Spring Security. I have created two roles, `ADMIN` and `CUSTOMER`, and for testing purposes I am trying to secure a particular endpoint `/api/v1/customers/` so that only `ADMIN` can access it.

As it turns out none of the roles, even `ADMIN` is also unable to access it. I realised I previously wasn't using `api/v1/customers` and just using `/customers/` so I fixed that.

Also based on an answer regarding a similar issue I have entered same end point twice, with and without slash in the end (check the config code, you'll know).

Nothing seems to work, I am sharing my `SecurityConfig` and controller (only useful parts) classes below.

**CustomerController.java**

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class CustomerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers(){
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{
    
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        // disabling the csrf isn't really the best way of dealing with this, need to fix !!!
        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/customers/", "/api/v1/customers").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().
                .and()
            .formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected InMemoryUserDetailsManager configureAuthentication(){

        List<UserDetails> userDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        List<GrantedAuthority> customerRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        customerRoles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("CUSTOMER"));
        List<GrantedAuthority> adminRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        adminRoles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));

        userDetails.add(new User("user_customer", this.PasswordEncoder().encode("password"), customerRoles));
        userDetails.add(new User("user_admin", this.PasswordEncoder().encode("password"), adminRoles));
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder PasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dur naah mate, same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in javadoc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionOperations.html#hasRole(java.lang.String)) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionOperations.html#hasAnyRole(java.lang.String...)), `SecurityExpressionRoot`'s `.hasRole()` and `.hasAnyRole()` **methods add *"ROLE_"* prefix to passed arguments by default**, if you did not change this default `GrantedAuthority` prefix.
So, with `.hasRole("ADMIN")` spring-security will try to match actual authority name with *"ROLE_ADMIN"* instead of just *"ADMIN"*.

But your in-memory User has a `SimpleGrantedAuthority` with *"ADMIN"* authority, so you get 403 status as a result.

You can fix it in 3 ways:

1. save roles as `SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")` and `SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CUSTOMER")` (with prefix)
2. use `.hasAuthority()` instead of `.hasRole()` method - the first one doesn't change passed argument and doesn't add any prefixes.
3. override default prefix like this:

```java
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // <- no default prefix
    }
```